# Easy to turn off "preliminary" indicators?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Coming up to a final preview, the PDF was still reduced in image dpi, had simulated greyscale, and was without bleed and printer marks.  Worried that someone would down-the-line confuse it with the final print-quality file, I added a "preview - do not print" banner.  The text was placed on several pages but moved and sized differently to not obscure stuff to-be-proofed while still being conspicuous.

**How can I arrange to turn these off easily, with one setting and not going through to find them one-by-one?**

It's not on a master page because they are different (and not on every page, and there may be more than one master page).  I see InDesign has layers, but each page has a separate setting.  I see something called "tags" but have no idea what that feature does.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: I'd use a PDF watermark rather than changing anything in the Indesign file.

Comment: How would you do that so it's specified per-page and will appear automatically when I re-do the next PDF export?

Comment: I wouldn't do it "per page" I'd just add a watermark in the PDF that is on every page. You can configure the mark to only show when printed, and you can restrict the PDF so it ONLY prints in low resolution (which wouldn't be suitable for press) In addition, you can set all this up as an action in Acrobat so it's just a click. Doing things "per page" in InDesign is just making more work.

Comment: That runs into the same thing as I explained for why it's not on a master page.  "…but moved and sized differently to not obscure stuff to-be-proofed while still being conspicuous. "

Comment: Guess I don't really understand the "fear" of someone publishing the proof. If you mark it as a proof, it won't happen by mistake. Anyone actually proofing things should have the wherewithal to disregard a watermark. Sounds like your'e going to a great deal of trouble because you *really* don't trust whomever it is that is doing any proofing.

Comment: "If you mark it as a proof, it won't happen by mistake."  that's why I'm marking it.  Disregard: depends how subtle it is, I guess. One of the ads I got was so watermarked!  (It was an effort to make people understand that. There's proof for you.)  The effort is disorganized and someone may be tasked to go to the print shop without himself reviewing the files.

Comment: You can prevent printing entirely for the PDF... solves that issue. :) And I generally put PROOF in large red letters covering 80 of the page at 20% opacity.... clearly there... but doesn't actually prevent proofreading. Nothing is idiot-proof... and trying to make everything idiot-proof will be quite a challenge. :)

Comment: prevent printing entireabout the PDF > good point! I forgot about PDF security; it's usually just an annoyance.  I wonder if the copy-shop machines respect that flag, if they don't simply use Acrobat to print to the great-big-printer?

Comment: Well all of Acrobat's security can be easily cracked if one has the mind to.. but I've yet to run into anyone who has any interest in cracking a customer supplied "proof" PDF so they can reproduce it.